# Laravel gate error, no such table: permissions (SQL: select * from "permissions")

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

For laravel testing environment, Laravel gate is not working. In `phpunit.xml`
file,  I am using `sqlite` connection and `:memory:` as database.

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

In `AuthServiceProvider`, I am defining gate as in this code below.

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    $this->registerPolicies($gate);


    foreach($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        $gate->define($permission->name, function($user) {
            $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
        });
    }
}

protected function getPermissions() {
    return Permission::with('roles')->get();
}
```

So, when ever I run `phpunit`. It shows error  `no such table: permissions (SQL: select * from "permissions")`.

So, please guide how can I define gate after migration for testing environment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
  foreach($this->getPermissions() as $permission) {
            $gate->define($permission->name, function($user)use($permisson) {
                $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
            });
        }
```

if you do not use `use($permission)` the $permission will be undefined...